# Show that eigenvalues are non-negative from the two-dimensional Rayleigh Quotient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

> For the eigenvalue problem:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \nabla^2 \phi + \lambda \phi &= 0 \\
> \end{align*}
>   with the boundary condition along the entire boundary:
>   \begin{align*}
>   a(x,y) \phi + b(x,y) \nabla \phi \cdot \tilde{n} &= 0 \\
> \end{align*}
>   Use the following Rayleigh Quotient to demonstrate that all eigevalues are non-negative ($\lambda \ge 0$):
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lambda &= \frac{-\oint \phi \nabla \phi \cdot \tilde{n} \, ds + \iint_R \left| \nabla \phi \right|^2 \, dx \, dy}{\iint_R \phi^2 \, dx \, dy} \\
> \end{align*}

Clearly, the denominator is positive. Any eigenfunction can't be zero everywhere, or it wouldn't be an eigenfunction, and it's real valued so it's square is positive.

The numerator term on the right must be non-negative since the integrand is non-negative since it is the square of a real number.

The numerator terms on the left: I see no obvious reasons why this can't be negative and why this can't be larger than the term on the right and I'm not sure how to proceed in demonstrating that.

Comment: Replace the dot product of the gradient and the normal using the BC and exploit the signs of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: AFAIK, $b$ may be zero, so I can't safely divide. But if I could, I would get $\nabla \phi \cdot \tilde{n} = -\frac{a(x,y)}{b(x,y)} \phi$. I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Ordinarily one assumes $a$ and $b$ are both bounded below by positive constants. This gets you the first term in the numerator being positive or zero. Without an assumption roughly along these lines even existence of solution can fail.

Comment: What do you know about $a$ and $b$? You need to know something about $a$ and $b$.